# How do I create equal spacing between all my header buttons?

Tags: html, css

I am just a beginner and I am learning. So I would like to know the correct way of achieving this.I have created three buttons and added it to the header. I want equal spaces between them. What is the best way or correct way to do it? Is margin a good way to do it?

My CSS Style

```
.MainHeader{
    height:100px;
    width:688px;
    padding:inherit;
    border:1px solid blue;
    background-color:black;
    }
.BodyContainer{
    height:788px;
    width:688px;
    padding:inherit;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    background-color:white;
    }
.MainFooter{
    height: 100px;
    width: 688px;
    padding:inherit;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    background-color:black;
    }
.Button{
    display:block;
    height:30px;
    width:150px;
    padding :0px 5px;
    background:darkorange;
    border:1px solid black;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    font:bold 14px/30px arial;
    background: linear-gradient(white, blue);
    border-radius: 5px;
    }
a.Button{
    text-decoration: none;
    }

a.Button:hover{
    background: grey;
    }
ul{
    padding: 0;
    }
li{
    list-style:none;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right: 8.6px;
margin-left: 8.6px;
}
```

My HTML code

```
<div class="MainHeader">
    <div>
    <div>
        <ul>
        <li><a class="Button" href="http://www.google.com">Homepage</a></li>
        <li><a class="Button" href="http://www.google.com">Search</a></li>
        <li><a class="Button" href="http://www.google.com">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try margins? Sounds like a good option - but why ask? It's pretty easy to test, did you have issues with it?

Comment: I know how to do it with margins but since I am a beginner I wanted to know if margin is the best way/correct way to do it or if there are better ways of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

there is many ways to do that.
one is - making some margin:

```
li{
  list-style:none;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-right:10px;
}
```

there is no such thing like "correct way" of doing such thing - but usual way is setting a margin

Comment: In the above code, my header container is 688px wide. My buttons are each 212px (total 636 px) wide, now i tried to add left margin and right margin of 8.66 but it displays one of the buttons at the button. What am I doing wrong? {
    list-style:none;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right: 8.6px;
    margin-left: 8.6px;
   }

Comment: if you set all your sizes and margins on .button - and set all margins and paddings to 0 on ul and li - it will be easier for you to calculate total width of your buttons. I think best for you will be right-clicking (in browser) on a button and choosing "inspect" - then on the panel below try "computed styles" tab - where you can change sizes and see what happens.